# Ruby on Rails redirect and send data to PHP script

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, get

I have a script on Ruby on Rails. It has to redirect to a PHP script in a different server. But I also need this PHP script to receive some data from Rails, preferably hidden somewhere (as raw data, or as a post).

Then the PHP will receive that data and do something with it (I actually want to start a session for the current user on the PHP server).

How can I acheieve this? Or something close to this?

---

I need something very similar to what happens when I submit an HTML form via POST. I need it to send data via POST AND to redirect to the given URL.

When I do

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(URL), {k: 'somek', u: someu, p: somep, e: somee})
```

It stays where it is.

Comment: You need to provide more context here, and some example code. What have you already tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028923/how-do-you-redirect-to-an-external-website-with-rails)?  Basically redirect in your controller to whatever external site and query string you desire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending POST in ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543143/sending-post-in-ruby)

Comment: i'm editing my question. but when I send post it is not following the URL

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: @steveklein but the data will remain visible wont it?

Comment: If you send a redirect to a user's browser, NOTHING will be hidden if the user cares to see it. How critical is the information? You can only maintain security if you encrypt the data or use a back-channel so the PHP system can directly ask your Rails system for the data based on a user ID or a token you provide the PHP session.

Comment: i just want the information to not be visible in the url. i will actually get this info and write it to the html, I believe. but nothing should be visible in the URL. the PHP will wait for a response, it cannot request it from Ruby.